# Do I have to think of $V$ as a model of set theory?

Tags: set-theory

Many approaches consider $V$ a fixed model of set theory (say $\textsf{ZF}$). Then what $V$ thinks to be true is actually *true*, and whenever we say *$\varphi$ holds* we mean that $\varphi$ is true in $V$. But if we fix $V$ as a model, then $V$ invariably satisfies (or refutes) all statements that are independent of $\textsf{ZF}$.

My question: can I think of $V$ as a "minimal" model (informally) in the sense that $V$ satisfies exactly the theory of $\textsf{ZF}$ and nothing else? We can easily show that $V$ satisfies all the axioms of $\textsf{ZF}$ (even though we cannot prove this uniformly, of course). Hence all logical consequences of $\textsf{ZF}$ hold in $V$ as well.

Is this approach sound? Or should I fix $V$ (at least mentally) as a model of $\textsf{ZF}$ (in some larger universe)?

Comment: No, you cannot think of $V$ that way. Regarding your last paragraph, you do not need to think of $V$ as a small model in a larger universe. Instead, $V$ *is* the universe.

Comment: (There is a modern approach where we do not think of a single universe, as suggested in the previous comment, but as one of several universes in a larger *multiverse*. I think understanding this view requires prior familiarity with the suggestion that $V$ is the universe, and so it is not "minimal" in any reasonable sense. Once you are comfortable with this view, then -- but not before --  it makes sense to explore the multiverse approach.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thank you Andrés, yes I have heard of the multiverse approach (Hamkins' paper from 2012 at least). Formally, what stops me from thinking of $V$ the way I was hoping to?

Comment: While Joel's multiverse may have been the most famous one, I think that most set theorists will agree that it is not a serious contender for a multiverse of sets starting with $V$. Instead, I think most people would like to think that at the very least all the set theoretic universes share the same ordinals, or at least agree on the notion of an ordinal (i.e. their ordinals are initial segments of one another). The Hamkins multiverse is one where everything is terribly ill-founded (so much that if you remove the genericity requirement, a particular singleton can be the whole multiverse).

Comment: @AsafKaragila That is interesting Asaf, what would be a good source for an exposition of the type of more conventioonal multiverse approach you're describing?

Comment: There's plenty of slides from talks discussing **the generic multiverse**. That is, start with a model of ZFC, and consider all the generic extensions you can get, and any ground model of those extensions. Probably some papers too.

Comment: "Formally, what stops me from thinking of $V$ the way I was hoping to?" The same reason that stops you from thinking that 4 is a prime number or that right angles are acute.

Comment: @Andrés: Public opinion and peer pressure? :D